# Enable Auth on mongodb

Tags: mongodb, authentication, authorization, database-administration

I am working on enabling auth on mongodb 3.4 following the instructions from, 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/

When i try to connect mongo client and authenticate during connection, using

```
mongo --port 27017 -u "myUserAdmin" -p "abc123" --authenticationDatabase "admin"
```

I get:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.4.4
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/
MongoDB server version: 3.4.4
2017-05-12T09:48:13.774-0500 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: Authentication failed. :
DB.prototype._authOrThrow@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1459:20
@(auth):6:1
@(auth):1:2
exception: login failed
```

I also tried authenticating after connecting mongo client,

```
db.auth("myUserAdmin", "abc123" )

Error: Authentication failed.
```

I am on centos 7, Please help!!

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your mongo config file /etc/mongod.conf

```
security:
  authorization: enabled
```

Comment: So: was the problem that your server had been running without authorization enabled?

Comment: Yes it was the issue. When we don't have authorization enabled in config it always says authentication failed even when you try to connect the client using valid username and password

Comment: This step should be mentioned in mongo enable auth docs in workflow but unfortunately its not there in that flow.

Comment: It says it clearly enough I think, at the [Re-start the MongoDB instance with access control.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/#re-start-the-mongodb-instance-with-access-control) stage.

Comment: Yes but that was not working for me on centos 7. It never describes adding something in config.  Its says restart mongod instance with --auth and this only worked for me on windows but not on linux.